# Coredata accessing a member with of a relationship with KVC notation

Tags: core-data, fetch, nsmanagedobject

I have two entities in coredata:

Voice described like:

```
NSString *code

NSString *description
```

and

Movement described like:

```
NSDate *date

NSString *notes

Voice *voice
```

I need to write down something like this (and i must use a generic NSManagedObject and NSObject)

```
NSManagedObject *currentManagedObject = [fetchedController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSObject *value = [currentManagedObject valueForKey:@"voice.description"];
```

The fetch is executed over a list of Movement entities.

But when I execute the code I receive this error:

```
012-02-09 01:52:15.843 MyApplication[1846:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Movement 0x16e680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Movement is not key value coding-compliant for the key "voice.description".
```

Is there a way to solve this issue using a generic access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've just solved the problem changing valueForKey method with valuerForKeyPath method.

Thank you